# Send image to Google Drive API from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I managed to upload text files to google API with this code

```
google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth
})
var media = {
  mimeType: 'text/plain',
  body: 'text'
}
drive.files.create({
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
})
```

But if i try to upload an image as suggested in documentation i'm getting empty file on the drive.
Trying to do that this way (file exists and has all privileges)

```
const drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth
})
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/png',
  body: fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/logo.png'))
}
drive.files.create({
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
})
```

And when I overviewing request in debug console i see that there was no request body.[image]

Please, help.

Below is the whole component which is doing the upload

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-success mb-3" @click="connect">Syncronize</button>
    <h3 class="text-center">
      <template v-if="getToken">Sync success</template>
      <template v-else>Sync failed</template>
    </h3>
    <button @click="tryUpload">Test API</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import OAuth2 from '../classes/OAuth2'
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  const {google} = require('googleapis')

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'getToken'
      ])
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'saveToken'
      ]),
      connect () {
        (async () => {
          let token = await new OAuth2().getToken()
          this.saveToken(token)
        })()
      },
      tryUpload () {
        const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
          '....',
          '.....',
          'http://127.0.0.1:42813/callback'
        )
        auth.setCredentials(this.getToken)
        const drive = google.drive({
          version: 'v3',
          auth
        })
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/logo.png'))
        var media = {
          mimeType: 'image/png',
          body: stream
        }
        drive.files.create({
          media: media,
          fields: 'id'
        }, function (err, file) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err)
          } else {
            console.log('File Id: ', file.id)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think that your below script in your question can correctly upload an image file with the filename of `Untitled`. So can you show us the content of the file of `21 bytes` you uploaded? And also, can you provide the whole script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: 21 bytes is the string of payload "imgs/logo--assets.png" . That is exact content of that file. The whole script itself is Vue.js application mounted in electron.js and bundled with webpack 4. Uploading function executes in "like" browser chromium. And also provided this component

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your script, I think that the script for uploading the image file works. But in this case, the file metadata is not set. So for example, how about setting the file metadata? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. So if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yeah, i already tried with metadata too. Setting metadata changes api method call but this call also sending wrong data. Thank you for your afforts

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment didn't resolve your issue. As a test run, when only the script for uploading the image file is run on the terminal by Node.js, what result will you get? If the file could be correctly uploaded, it can be considered that the reason of the issue occurs at other part except for the script for uploading file. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the file with require instead

```
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/png',
  body: require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/logo.png'))
}
```

As it is, you are uploading the stream itself, not the file being streamed. If you want to use fs, you should try accessing the stream using the callback inside of the `stream.on('{event}' function () {})` method.

Comment: Thank you for affort. But no luck. If i do require, it starts  sending it like this http://prntscr.com/rcovol but on the Google.drive it creates file with 21 bytes.

Comment: I also tried to set all that in stream.on('load', () => {......}) but that changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me when I upload a file using arrow functions syntax and async/await (at least for me it's more comfortable like this):

```
// Your tryUpload Function
const tryUpload = async () => {

    // ...Previous OAuth workflow

    // Build Drive service  
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    try {
        const data = await uploadFile(drive);
        console.log(data);
    } catch(err){
        console.log(`There was a problem in the promise ---> ${err}`);
    }
} 

const uploadFile = (drive) =>{
    // Set file metadata and data
    const fileMetadata = {'name': 'testupload.png'};
    const media = {
      mimeType: 'image/png',
      // If it's in the same dir, just pass 'testupload.png'
      body: fs.createReadStream('path/to/testupload.png') 
    };
    // Return the Promise result after completing its task
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Call Files: create endpoint
      return drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media
      },(err, results) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(results))
    });
};
```

### Docs

As a guide to help you. I used these docs:

[Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

[Perform a simple upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple).